# How to JSON Serialize a Python Class Object?

Tags: python, json, api, output, paapi

My goal is to write the response I get from a call to Amazon's Product Advertising API to a file in JSON format.

I call the API using

```
response = default_api.search_items(search_items_request)
```

I attempt to write the results to a file using:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(response, f)
```

I get the error message:

```
TypeError : Object of type 'SearchItemsResponse' is not JSON serializable
```

How can I fix this? I need to write the response in JSON. A solution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

json only knows about standard data types -- int, float, list, string, dictionary, etc.

If you want to save an arbitrary class object with json, you'll have to write a custom dump routine that decomposes the object into those basic types, and a custom load routine that reads those basic types and reconstructs the object.

If you're able, it might be a lot easier to use pickle instead, which does support saving arbitrary class objects.

Comment: Can I use pickle to save into JSON? From what I see, Pickle only serializes and de-serializes into its own format.

Comment: I don't believe pickle and json are interchangeable.